# using case statements query to read data in sql with php

Tags: php

I am trying to display data in a table format on a web page using case statement in PhP, and I cant get any results and with no error message. I used the following code;

> 

```
***$sql = "SELECT D.name, count(*),
sum (case when p.status=250  then 1 else 0 end) as January,
sum (case when p.status>300 then 1 else 0 end) as FEB,
sum (case when p.status>400 then 1 else 0 end) as MARCH,
sum (case when p.status>500 then 1 else 0 end) as APRIL,
sum (case when p.status>550 then 1 else 0 end) as MAY,
sum (case when p.status>600 then 1 else 0 end) as JUNE
FROM person p
join PersonCard pc on pc.PersonId=p.PersonId
join Village V on V.VillageId = P.PlaceOfRegistrationId
join section S on s.SectionId = V.SectionId
join Chiefdom c on C.ChiefdomId = S.ChiefdomId
join District D on D.DistrictId = C.DistrictId 
where d.districtId>0
group by d.name
order by d.name"
;
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
    
      for ($i = 0; $i < $stmt; $i++) {
      $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array ($stmt);
      echo "<tr>";
      //echo "<td>$i</td>";
     
          echo "<td>" . $row["D.NAME"] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row["january"] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row["FEB"] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row["MARCH"] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row["APRIL"] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row["MAY"] . "</td>";***
```

Comment: Please [edit] question to explain how it is related to C#. The code shown in the post does not seem to be C# (nor JavaScript)... If you are looking for conversion to C# SO in not the right place to put that work order.

Comment: I have edited the question now

Comment: If you want this to work correctly with the 'case 'tests that you need to specify the range for each `sum(case... ` statement. Example: A value of 600 willl will be totaled in more than one sum over 300. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes that's what I want @RyanVincent